# Subl command ties up a terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2, gnome-terminal, terminator

I often use the

```
subl .
```

command to open folders in Sublime Text from the terminal (I use Terminator for Ubuntu usually). But there is something annoying about it. That process has to just keep running, tying up an entire terminal tab until i do ^C to stop it (which closes Sublime) or close the text editor.

This is somewhat irritating. On my Mac, the terminal and iTerm lets me just move on to another line after opening sublime from the terminal. What gives? Anyone know how to fix this or do I have to just deal with it and tell my grandkids about the hard days of wasted screen real estate during the Great Recession?

Thanks!

Comment: please, say your subl and terminator version.

Comment: Have you aliased `subl -w` to `subl`?

Comment: Using Sublime Text 2.02 and Terminator 0.96.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo. That's what does it! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
---> ~/bin/subl -help
Sublime Text 2 Build 2221

Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories
   or: subl [arguments] -               edit stdin

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:        Keep the application activated after closing the file
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

--wait is implied if reading from stdin. Use --stay to not switch back
to the terminal when a file is closed (only relevant if waiting for a file).

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

I use the `-s` flag.

```
alias subl='~/bin/subl -s'
```